# Resize UIImage in in asynchronous mode, using AFNetworking

Tags: ios, ios5, uiimageview, uiimage, afnetworking

I am using AFNetwork in my application to get some data from my web service.
In these data, there are some images with random sizes, I need to add some UIImageView.

My problem is to **adjust the image in the correct scale** of UIImageView, in asynchronous mode.

Any idea how to do this?

**EDIT**

I am using the normal method of the Afnetwoking´s projects:

```
 [self setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"img_my_nophoto"]];
```

The logic inside this method is :

```
- (void)setImageWithURLRequest:(NSURLRequest *)urlRequest 
          placeholderImage:(UIImage *)placeholderImage 
                   success:(void (^)(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, UIImage *image))success
                   failure:(void (^)(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error))failure
{
    [self cancelImageRequestOperation];

UIImage *cachedImage = [[[self class] af_sharedImageCache] cachedImageForRequest:urlRequest];
if (cachedImage) {
    self.image = cachedImage;
    self.af_imageRequestOperation = nil;

    if (success) {
        success(nil, nil, cachedImage);
    }
} else {
    self.image = placeholderImage;

    AFImageRequestOperation *requestOperation = [[AFImageRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:urlRequest];
    [requestOperation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        if ([[urlRequest URL] isEqual:[[self.af_imageRequestOperation request] URL]]) {
            self.image = responseObject;
            self.af_imageRequestOperation = nil;
        }

        if (success) {
            success(operation.request, operation.response, responseObject);
        }

        [[[self class] af_sharedImageCache] cacheImage:responseObject forRequest:urlRequest];


    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        if ([[urlRequest URL] isEqual:[[self.af_imageRequestOperation request] URL]]) {
            self.af_imageRequestOperation = nil;
        }

        if (failure) {
            failure(operation.request, operation.response, error);
        }

    }];

    self.af_imageRequestOperation = requestOperation;

        [[[self class] af_sharedImageRequestOperationQueue] addOperation:self.af_imageRequestOperation];
    }
}
```

The full class code:
https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/blob/master/AFNetworking/UIImageView%2BAFNetworking.m

**SOLUTION**

I solve my problem setting the UIImageView with

self.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;

self.clipsToBounds=YES;

basically this set the image with the proper scale, and cut all the edges..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit:

If I understand your problem correctly, you just need to set `imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit` on the ImageView you get from the Afnetworking FW.

Or you could check the actual size of the image with: `imageView.image.size` and set the imageView's frame accordingly.

Comment: i don´t want to resize the UIImageView, i need to update the UImage to scale correctly accordion the UIImageView aspect ratio... all this using Afnetworking framework..

Comment: Oh allright, I don't know that framework. Could you post the code you're using to create the image view? It's hard to help without knowing what you're doing...

Comment: yes of course. i just edited my question. Since i dont know the size of the UIImage provide by the server, i dont know how to scale it in a assinc way in this class...

Comment: if i used that option the UIImage scale himself inside the UIImageView, and blank areas around the UIImage will could appear...

Comment: sorry for my late reply :(

Comment: sorry for my late reply :( i solve my problem setting the UIImageView with :self.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
      self.clipsToBounds=YES;

Answer (score 6):

There is a variant of the AF `UIImageView` category that calls a block when the asynchronous image request is complete.

You can resize the returned image in the success block and assign it to the image view. See

```
- (void)setImageWithURLRequest:(NSURLRequest *)urlRequest 
              placeholderImage:(UIImage *)placeholderImage 
                       success:(void (^)(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, UIImage *image))success
                       failure:(void (^)(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error))failure
```

Once the image has been resized, make sure you assign the image to the `UIImageView` on the main queue using GCD as the block will be called in a background thread.

Here's an example using a UIIImageView with its content mode set to AspectFill. Resizing using Core Graphics will usually look better than having the UIImageView rescale the image.

```
__weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
CGSize targetSize = self.targetImageView.bounds.size;
[self.targetImageView setImageWithURL:photoURL success:^(UIImage *image) {

    CGFloat imageHeight = image.size.height;
    CGFloat imageWidth = image.size.width;

    CGSize newSize = targetSize;
    CGFloat scaleFactor = targetSize.width / imageWidth;
    newSize.height = imageHeight * scaleFactor;

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, NO, 0.0);
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, newSize.width, newSize.height)];
    UIImage *small = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),^ {

        weakSelf.targetImageView.image = small;
    });

} failure:^(NSError *error) {
    // Handel the error here
}];
```

Comment: You shouldn't capture `self` strongly in blocks.

Comment: Updated answer to prevent capturing self.

Comment: Updated code to be class agnostic using __typeof(self)

Answer (score 0):

This is what `AFImageResponseSerializer` is for. Just change the image scale to match the image scale you're retrieving.

`AFImageResponseSerializer *imageResponseSerializer = [self.avatarImageView imageResponseSerializer];
    [imageResponseSerializer setImageScale:1.0];`